# POST route not found

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, reverse-proxy, digital-ocean

I have a node server with express that has two routes:

`app.post('/graphql', …)` `->` route just returns a dummy hi response

`app.get('*', …)` `->` route just returns a hello world string

When I run this locally and make a `POST` request to `http://localhost:3000/graphql/` I get the hi response from the `/graphql` route.

This is all running in a docker container with docker-compose.

The issue now is when I run this on a digitalocean server with the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name some-ip-address-here;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}

location /graphql/ {
    proxy_redirect          http://localhost:3000/  /graphql/;
    proxy_pass_header       Server;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_connect_timeout   5;
    proxy_read_timeout      240;
    proxy_intercept_errors  on;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}
```

}

When I visit `some-ip-address-here` I can see the response from `/` route but when I make a `POST` request to `some-ip-address-here:80/graphql/` I get a `404 not found` and in the nginx logs looks like

[image]

Thanks for all the help

Comment: in your  dummy response in app.post('/graphql', …) are you seeing any hits from some-ip-address-here:80/graphql/ in node.js ? Sometimes I put a console.log("function triggered") statement in there just to see if the requests are getting past nginx. Also what do you get with some-ip-address-here/graphql/ ? ( removing :80 from the request )

Comment: Thank you @NiallJG I was using an old docker image should have been logging this stuff :-( This helped a lot thank you!